# Set cookies programatically in Crosswalk WebView on Android

Tags: android, cordova, cookies, webview, crosswalk-runtime

I need to make Crosswalk on Android (in a Cordova project) use some
cookies I gathered via an Apache HttpClient.
However I'm not sure how to achieve this. I tried experimenting with
the XWalkCookieManager but I think everything I do with the
XWalkCookieManager is ignored. Where would I initialize the cookie
manager? Is this even supported yet?

```
//cookieStore contains the cookies I got via a request from the Apache
// HttpClient.
 List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
 for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
     Cookie cookie = cookies.get(i);
     String cookieString = buildCookieStringFromCookie(cookie);

     // This is a XWalkCookieManager I initialized earlier but it doesn't do anything 
     //as far as I can tell.
     cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(),cookieString);
 }
```

I would really appreciate any help, this is the only thing that
currently keeps me from using Crosswalk successfully.

I have also tried using the standard Android cookie Manager via `CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);` but this seems to be ignored by Crosswalk as well.

Best,

Andreas

//Edit for future reference:

The issue was that Crosswalk expects the cookie url to start with https:// and the native Android webview doesn't (or the other way around, I'm not sure anymore). Now what is working fine is to set the cookie twice, once without https and once with https:

```
   mCookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);
   mCookieManager.setCookie("https://" + cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an instance of XWalkCookieManager and set the differents cookies in it.
It seems to be shared accross the XwalkViews.

```
// Your can use this inside the onCreate() method
private XWalkCookieManager mCookieManager;
mCookieManager = new XWalkCookieManager();
mCookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
mCookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);

// Pass it to your request executor
httpRequestExecutor.setXWalkCookieManager(mCookieManager);
//You're now able to add your cookies to this manager rather than to your cookieManager
```

How we extract the cookies from the HttpResponse :

```
responseHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();
for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.length; i++)
{
    Header header = responseHeaders[i];
    if (header.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie"))
    {
        mCookieManager.setCookie(request.getUrl(), header.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: ahhh thank you very much! I didn't know about the "setXWalkCookieManager" method. I'll try this on Monday and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Actually setXWalkCookieManager is a custom method on my requestExecutor (in your project, it would be your class using HttpClient). In your case, you should just use mCookieManager rather than your cookieManager.

Comment: mhm I think I already tried that and it just didn't set any cookies. Do you know which version of crosswalk are you currently using?

Comment: I'm actually using crosswalk-webview-10.39.235.15-x86. I initialize the XWalkCookieManager during the onCreate method, then passing it to my requestExecutor which populate the cookies (authentication is made by the android part). It's actually working !

Comment: thanks a lot! I currently can't check, but maybe I was using an older version or there was some other error. It helps a lot to know that it's working for you, so I won't give up trying :-)

Comment: Hi Paqman, I have one more question: Are you setting all your cookies before you create the webview itself? Or are you really able to set cookies after the webview has already been used? I just can't seem to get this to work...

Comment: Hi, the webview is actually already created when I add some cookies. Are you sure your domain/string is alright ? I push you the extract code.

Comment: Maybe it's little bit counter-intuitive that you'll create `XWalkCookieManager` with constructor and not setting it anywhere. It's used by the webview automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of XWalkCooikeManager is a little different with Android CookieManager.
You should add schemes(http|https) before cookie.getDomain().

This is because the implementation of CookieManager in Android WebView use WebAddress(url).toString(), which will add schemes (http|https) into the url.
As the explanation in CooieManagerAdapter:
WebAddress is a private API in the android framework and a "quirk" of the Classic WebView implementation that allowed embedders to be relaxed about what URLs they passed into the CookieManager, so we do the same normalisation before entering the chromium stack.